# Ember.Object.create set and get

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a small problem with `Ember.Object.create()`. In my route in `setupController()`, I am trying to add new Ember Object to an array. Whenever I enter that route first I do `controller.set('onRules',[ ])` so I have an empty array onRules to which I want to add object and then I am creating new Ember object like that:

```
  controller.get('orRules').addObject(
      Ember.Object.create(
        {
          id: 0,
          isAllowedToDelete: false,
          foo: "bar"
        }
      )
    );
```

After that the object is being added to the array and when console.log orRules I can see that set and get functions are only available for id and isAllowedToDelete but not for foo. You can see it on following screenshot:

[orRules class in console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15Ktx.png)
Can somebody explain me why Ember decides to make available set and get functions only for two first properties and not for foo ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem here. I'm sure that `yourObject.get('foo')` and `yourObject.set('foo')` works.